# Titanium Appcelerator Android module : How to create a proxy?

Tags: android, module, proxy, appcelerator, creation

This is not a question but is an answer to the issues I was stuck up while creating custom Android module for Titanium appcelerator.

I was able to run the ExampleProxy provided by the framework but was having problems creating my own Proxy class.

I was able to access the proxy. After lot of search I got the reference of following question - 
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/153993/how-to-create-a-proxy#answer-264746

Following response partially works-

> "Thank you very much Benjamin Bahrenburg for the clarification. Also i
>   thank Mads for your quick response.
>
> Exact answer i was looking for : Need to remove the files in the bin,
>   libs, and build folder. Then do a clean, in Eclipse. After all of that
>   it tends to build. Please make sure you are using Ti 3.1.0 ( not 3.1.1
>   which has an issue)."

In addition on windows 7 machine I had following observations-

1. The Module-generated folder in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ must be deleted.
2. In the module folder delete following contents - entire contents of bin and libs and delete everything in build except \build\generated\Application.mk

Answer (score 0):

It cost my 1 day to solve this problem.

to successfully create and run a ViewProxy, you have to:

1. change its file/class name (from ExampleProxy) to ViewProxy
2. clean the dirty files, including:  `build/`,  `dist/`, and some "lib.so " files in `libs/` folder.
3. execute `ti clean` in your "Titanium app" folder.
4. your ViewProxy is `not the same` as the module name. e.g. your module name is: "GaodeMapModule", your proxy name should not be: "GaodeMapProxy", it doesn't work.